# #define vs. enums for addressing peripherals

Tags: c, enums, arm, embedded, c-preprocessor

I have to program peripheral registers in an ARM9-based microcontroller.

For instance, for the USART, I store the relevant memory addresses in an `enum`:

```
enum USART
{
    US_BASE = (int) 0xFFFC4000,
    US_BRGR = US_BASE + 0x16,
    //...
};
```

Then, I use pointers in a function to initialize the registers:

```
void init_usart (void)
{
    vuint* pBRGR = (vuint*) US_BRGR;
    *pBRGR = 0x030C;
    //...
}
```

But my teacher says I'd better use `#define`s, such as:

```
#define US_BASE (0xFFFC4000)
#define US_BRGR (US_BASE + 0x16)
#define pBRGR   ((vuint*) US_BRGR)

void init_usart (void)
{
    *pBRGR = 0x030C;
}
```

Like so, he says, you don't have the overhead of allocating pointers in the stack.

Personally, I don't like `#define`s much, nor other preprocessor directives.
So the question is, in this particular case, are `#define`s really worth using instead of `enum`s and stack-allocated pointers?

---

Related question: [Want to configure a particular peripheral register in ARM9 based chip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2461708/357851)

Comment: I'd be surprised if in a non-debug build the code generated by the compiler is any different.

Comment: I hate those teachers who just say: "Use this", so students have later to dig themselves for reasons. Usually those teachers don't know the answers themselves.

Comment: If you define your pointers as static, they won't be allocated on the stack. If you also declare them const, then they may not even cause memory to be allocated in the data area (but this will depend on the specific compiler your are using)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood your instructor.  The enums are fine, there is no reason to use a pointer to an int instead of an int.  You can do `int i = *(int *) some_thing;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The approach I've always preferred is to first define a struct reflecting the peripherals register layout

```
typedef volatile unsigned int reg32; // or other appropriate 32-bit integer type
typedef struct USART
{
    reg32 pad1;
    reg32 pad2;
    reg32 pad3;
    reg32 pad4;
    reg32 brgr;
    // any other registers
} USART;

USART *p_usart0 = (USART * const) 0xFFFC4000;
```

Then in code I can just use

```
p_usart0->brgr = 0x030C;
```

This approach is much cleaner when you have multiple instances of the same sort of peripheral:

```
USART *p_usart1 = (USART * const) 0xFFFC5000;
USART *p_usart2 = (USART * const) 0xFFFC6000;
```

User sbass provided a link to [an excellent column](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4027659/Alternative-Models-for-Memory-Mapped-Devices) by Dan Saks that gives much more detail on this technique, and points out its advantages over other approaches.

If you're lucky enough to be using C++, then you can add methods for all the common operations on the peripheral and nicely encapsulate the devices peculiarities.

Comment: This is much better. TI uses this method for their procesors (at least, for 28xx DSPs and MSP430). The method for locating registers is a little different; it sticks them in particular sections and uses the linker file to locate them at a specific address.

Comment: Also you should have the whole structure be volatile, not just the individual components.

Comment: @Jason, If all the registers are declared volatile, then declaring the entire struct volatile won't make any difference. In either case, the compiler is not allowed to optimise away any explicit reads or writes to the registers.

Comment: @Jason, Stephen: volatiles are often miscompiled: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/emsoft08-preprint.pdf  And specifically, even on newest version of gcc and clang, volatile structs are miscompiled: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/274

Comment: @pkh Thanks for the references. If I could edit comments, I should change my reply to Jason from "declaring the entire struct volatile won't make any difference" to "declaring the entire struct volatile shouldn't make any difference".

Comment: @StephenC.Steel: Your link is broken. Please [update it](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4027659/Alternative-Models-for-Memory-Mapped-Devices).  Additionally you might want to mention another post from this site: [Memory Mapped Devices as C++ Classes](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4200755/Memory-mapped-devices-as-C--classes-item-1)

Comment: I feel urged to point out, that more often than one would like, one has to use the solution given by some specific embedded development environment. Whether nor not there is right and wrong about how to do it - the risk of re-writing whatever is already there is not worth it.

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid that `enum` are a dead end for such a task. The standard defines `enum` constants to be of type `int`, so in general they are *not* compatible with pointers.

One day on an architecture with 32bit `int` and 64bit pointers you might have a constant that doesn't fit into an `int`. It is not well defined what will happen.

On the other hand the argument that `enum` would allocate something on the stack is not valid. They are compile time constants and have nothing to do with the function stack or no more than any constants that you specify through macros.

Comment: @Michael: but that can be fixed by adding `UL` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Dan Saks has written a number of columns on this for Embedded Systems Programming. Here's one of his [latest ones](http://v2.embedded.com/columns/technicalinsights/224700534). He discusses C, C++, enums, defines, structs, classes, etc. and why you might one over another. Definitely worth reading and always good advice.

Comment: Possibly moved to [here](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4208573/Accessing-memory-mapped-classes) or  [here](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4027659/Alternative-Models-for-Memory-Mapped-Devices)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, one big reason to use `#define` for this kind of thing is that it's more of the standard idiom used in the embedded community.

Using enums instead of `#define` will generate questions/comments from instructors (and in the future, colleagues), even when using other techniques might have other advantages (like not stomping on the global identifier namespace).

I personally like using enums for numeric constants, but sometimes you need to do what is customary for what and where you're working.

However, performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is always do whatever the teacher wants and pass the class then on your own question everything and find out if their reasons were valid and form your own opinions.  You cant win against the school, not worth it.

In this case it is easy to compile to assembler or disassemble to see the difference if any between the enum and define.

I would recommend the define over enum, have had compiler discomfort with enums.  I highly discourage using pointers the way you are using them, I have seen every compiler fail to accurately generate the desired instructions, it is rare but when it happens you will wonder how your last decades of coding ever worked.  Pointing structs or anything else is considerably worse.  I often get flamed for this, and expect to this time around.  Too many miles around the block, fixed too much broken code with these problems to ignore the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily say that either way is better. It is just personal preference. As for your professor's argument, it is really a moot point. Allocating variables on the stack is one instruction, no matter how many there are, usually in the form `sub esp, 10h`. So if you have one local or 20, it is still one instruction to allocate the space for all of them.

I would say that the one advantage of the #include is that if for some reason down the road you wanted to change how that pointer is accessed, you just need to change it in one location.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend towards using an enum, for potential future compatibility with C++ code.  I say this because at my job, we have a lot of C header files shared between projects, some of which use C code and some of which use C++.  For those using C++, we'd often like to wrap the definitions in a namespace, to prevent symbol masking, but you can't assign a #define to a namespace.